# Checkbox condition in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a responsive menu.

Here is my code:

```css
#web-menu {
  max-width: 1235px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #444;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  display: block;
}
#web-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}
#web-menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 37px;
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  display: block;
}
#web-menu li > ul {
  display: none;
  width: 20em;
  /* Width to help Opera out */
  z-index: 10;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#web-menu li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#web-menu li:hover li {
  float: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
#web-menu a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #1a1a1a;
}
#web-menu a:active {
  background: #444;
  /*turns this color briefly when link is selected*/
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px),
only screen and (max-device-width: 900px) {
  #web-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  #web-menu li:hover > ul {
    display: none;
  }
  #web-menu li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  [id=main-mobile-menu]:checked ~ #web-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  [id=mobile-menu-1]:checked + #web-menu li > ul {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="main-mobile-menu">Show Menu</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="main-mobile-menu" role="button">

<ul id="web-menu">
  <li id="web-menu-home"><a href="index.php">Home</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="mobile-menu-1" role="button">
    <label for="mobile-menu-1" class="mobile-menu1">Show Menu</label>
    <a href="#">E-Resources</a>
    <ul>
      <li id="web-menu-top"><b>Resources</b>
      </li>
      <li id="web-menu-cdcs"><a href="/index.php?page_id=39">Tests</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is, the checkbox label is only working if the related css id is not an li. Any idea where im making mistake?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The `for` attribute only works on form element ids.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems:

1. You used the `+` selector, which would require that the `<ul>` immediately follow `#mobile-menu-1`. Changing this to `~` resolves that issue.
2. You have a specificity problem where `[id=mobile-menu-1]:checked ~ ul` (21) is not strong enough to override `#web-menu li > ul` (102). Giving the `<ul>` an ID and updating the selector does the trick.

(I used https://specificity.keegan.st/ to calculate the specificity.)

```css
#web-menu {
  max-width: 1235px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #444;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  display: block;
}
#web-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}
#web-menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 37px;
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  display: block;
}
#web-menu li > ul {
  display: none;
  width: 20em;
  /* Width to help Opera out */
  z-index: 10;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#web-menu li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#web-menu li:hover li {
  float: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
#web-menu a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #1a1a1a;
}
#web-menu a:active {
  background: #444;
  /*turns this color briefly when link is selected*/
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px),
only screen and (max-device-width: 900px) {
  #web-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  #web-menu li:hover > ul {
    display: none;
  }
  #web-menu li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  [id=main-mobile-menu]:checked ~ #web-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  [id=mobile-menu-1]:checked ~ #sub-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="main-mobile-menu">Show Menu</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="main-mobile-menu" role="button">

<ul id="web-menu">
  <li id="web-menu-home"><a href="index.php">Home</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="mobile-menu-1" role="button">
    <label for="mobile-menu-1" class="mobile-menu1">Show Menu</label>
    <a href="#">E-Resources</a>
    <ul id="sub-menu">
      <li id="web-menu-top"><b>Resources</b>
      </li>
      <li id="web-menu-cdcs"><a href="/index.php?page_id=39">Tests</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```